How drag and adjust the image in a imageView then mask that imageview with another imageview
I can make a story make r application simpaly i can call json to create layout programatically in this: I can pick an image from Gallary and make it mask the selected object. Give me the coding side solution. I clearly mention sample images I want.

[
here is my Json:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EDPZJhl8sTDJXs6jX_97irPw211VxPia/view?usp=sharing
Note : please help me with java

You didn't provided any piece of your code or json file, so I can't help much.
But if you've created layout like image you provided, I assume json file you have specifies the path of masks.
If you have path of the mask and bitmap(or Drawable) of user-picked image, then you may use Canvas.clipPath() and canvas.drawBitmap()(or Drawable.draw()) in onDraw() of your custom View.
Example:
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    clipPath.reset()
    // Set path of mask you want
    // clipPath.addOval(bound, Path.Direction.CW)
    canvas?.withClip(clipPath) {
        // Draw image to location you want
        // canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint)
    }
}

Or, if you already placed ImageView and have hard time drawing images yourself, you may create custom ViewGroup which sets clip before drawing its children(ImageViews in your case).
override fun dispatchDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    clipPath.reset()
    // Set path of masks you want
    // clipPath.addOval(bound, Path.Direction.CW)
    // clipPath.addCircle(hCenter, vCenter, rad - padding, Path.Direction.CCW)
    canvas?.withClip(clipPath) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas) // This triggers children to draw themselves, clipped with clipPath
    }
}

Again, if you want more help, you'll want to provide more information and things you've tried.
